# c++ using <functional> and <algorithm> to split a vector into 2 at a certain point

Tags: c++

I need to plit a vector into two at a certain point. That point can be any string. Now my thought was to use  find to find that string and put it into a itterator. But is there a way to get the index from that itterator so I can use that to split the vector? And would http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition_point/ do the same thing? I don't need code just a hint in the right direction.

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the index, there's a [`std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking a pair of iterators for the range of elements to copy into the vector.

That means you can simply find the element where you want to split the existing vector, and use that as the end when creating the first vector, and the beginning when creating the second vector.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector's iterators are random access ones, meaning you can subtract one iterator from another to get the distance between them. Therefore, converting an iterator to element's index is a matter of subtracting `vec.begin()` from it.

Then, you shouldn't need an index in the first place, as you can construct a vector from a pair of iterators.

As for partitioning, it's not the same as splitting. Partitioning just rearranges a sequence such that all the elements that are less than a pivot element precede that pivot element in rearranged sequence.